# Sed - Obtain all occurrence

Tags: html, bash, macos

I'm trying to create script to edit a xhtml file. I want to replace the reference tag address for the referenced text. For example:

input:

```
This is an example with <a href="Ref1">three</a> references.
The first reference is at the <a href="Ref2">first line</a> and the rest is at <a href="Ref2">the second line</a>.
```

output:

```
This is an example with <a href="three">three</a> references.
The first reference is at the <a href="first%20line">first line</a> and the rest is at <a href="the%20second%20line">the second line</a>.
```

I had thought use SED command in two parts. First of all get the referenced text and next replace the address, but I'm stuck on the first SED command.

With the following command I have come to obtain the last referenced text by line:

```
sed -n 's:.*">\(.*\)</a>.*:\1:p' File.xml
```

How do I obtain all occurrence?

Comment: What if you remove `-n` from command line & replace `:p` by `:g` at the end...?

Comment: @anishsane Yes, I did it. The result is the same (also it prints the lines without coincidence). And if I add `:g` without delete `:p` I obtain the same result too.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see those `.*`... Try this: `sed 's:href="[^"]*"\([^>]*>\)\([^<]*\):href="\2"\1\2:g' File.xml`

Comment: On an irrelevant note, what you are calling as [`coincidence`](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:coincidence) should actually be called as [`occurrence`](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:occurrence). But I understand that you are not a native English speaker; so, it's OK...

Comment: Yes, I mean occurrence. Your last suggestion does not work. It prints all the text of the file.

Comment: It matches your expected output that you mentioned... `:-/` If you want only the `innerHTML` of the `a` tag, use this: `grep -o '(?<=>)[^<]*(?=</a>)' File.xml`

Comment: With the `grep`it doesn't work .... nothing prints, `:(` I'm using the example file of my question for the test.

Comment: Sorry, I missed `-P` : `grep -oP '(?<=>)[^<]*(?=</a>)' File.xml`

Comment: Thanks again for the help ... but accordding to the manual of `grep` the option `-P` is not available. I'm working on OSX.

Comment: `perl -nE 'say for /(?<=>)([^<]*)(?=<\/a>)/g' File.xml` ?

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! But now I need save the occurrence for replace the address. Any suggestions? I am trying to use an array but if the text contains spaces separtes for words.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will convert your example as requested (it uses the BDS sed syntax):

```
function copy_link_text_to_href()
{
    sed -E 's:[^"]+">([^<]+)</a>:\1">\1</a>:g'
}

function url_escape_one_space_per_href()
{
    sed -E 's/(<a href="[^" ]+) +/\1%20/g'
}

cat File.xhtml                  \
| copy_link_text_to_href        \
| url_escape_one_space_per_href \
| url_escape_one_space_per_href
```

Note that the function `url_escape_one_space_per_href` must be applied as many times as there may be spaces inside a single link. Probably you will have to call that function in a loop until its input remains unchanged.

> Caveat: This script will work not as expected if the link text contains quotes.

Comment: With the first `sed` command it prints (in this case copy) all the text of the file.

Comment: @Pepe What do you mean? Doesn't it replace the `href` value?

Comment: I have tried the first function (copy_link_text_to_href) and it doesn't work. It copies all text of the file.

Comment: @Pepe The function is supposed to print its output on stdout (on the screen) rather than replace the contents of the file. But you didn't answer my question - does it replace hrefs or not?

Comment: @Pepe In other words - does `<a href="Ref1">` become `<a href="three">` in its output?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The output is the same, it doesn't replace the `href` value. I had tried the first sed command (`'s:[^"]\+">\([^<]\+\)</a>:\1">\1</a>:g'`) separately and as it didn't copy the referenced text I had not tried the entire code.

Comment: @Pepe That may be due to the difference of sed under osx compared to gnu sed. Will try to fix it shortly.

Comment: Link text should not contain `"`. It should have been converted to `&quot;` :P

Comment: @Leon It works. Thanks a lot! But the result is printed on terminal. How can I save changes to the same xhtmm file?

Comment: @anishsane Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Pepe You must save to a temporary file and then rename it (overwrite the input file)

Comment: @Pepe Something like this: `cat File.xhtml | copy_link_text_to_href | url_escape_one_space_per_href | url_escape_one_space_per_href > File.xhtml.fixed && mv File.xhtml.fixed File.xhtml`